# Facing issue while binding the Grid view in one of the servers

Tags: windows, oracle

we are using three servers to host our application. Two of them are production servers and we are using load balancing in those servers and one of them is a development server. Everything was working fine until recently when one of the listener ports for our oracle database got changed, after which we are not getting any data in one of the grid view. We got the new port opened so the issue got resolved in one of the production server but it is still there in the other two servers. I know that the server is able to connect to the oracle DB because one more page in my application is able to get the data from Oracle DB and also when i tried to do a TNS ping to the Oracle database it is returning a value. There is this one page which is not able to bind the data.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try to debug? Connection itself is not happening or the data is not coming?

Comment: The same thing was working properly earlier all of a sudden it stopped working and i am able to see the data just fine in my local and when i tried pinging the DB server the ping request is also going

Comment: Any error on the page that's not working or in the log? If tnsping is working then you should get some ora error which can be helpful to troubleshoot?

Comment: I am getting this error in event logs don't know if this is the reason or not"The Template Persistent Cache initialization failed for Application Pool 'pad-oronite' because of the following error: Could not create a Disk Cache Sub-directory for the Application Pool. The data may have additional error codes"

Comment: I don't think this could be the reason as you mentioned that other page in same application is working, so they both would be using same application pool. Though you can check by resolving it.  Refer to [link] (http://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2010/07/template-persistent-cache-error-with-classic-asp-under-iis-7/) for instructions

Comment: Hi Nimesh the solution you gave that also did not solve my issue

Comment: Do you see anything in the log files at the time of connection? check the log file present under ORACLE_HOME directory. It's hard to provide more information as there is no error code mentioned anywhere.